# MBean equivalent for JBoss 7

Tags: jboss, jmx

Is there a way to create an MBean and expose it in the management interface of JBoss 7?

I got the may idea to create a Bean with **@Singleton** and **@Named** annotations but I would like to be able to read its attributes and invoke its operations like it was in JBoss 4, 5, 6.

Thank you.
SK

Comment: How are you planning to read the MBean's state and invoke operations on it? Through a management console, or through your own code? In either case you can register your MBean with JBoss' MBeanServer, but how you plan to "see" the MBean determines how much work you will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Starting JBoss 7 (not sure which dot version exactly), the JBoss specific JMX implementation has been completely removed. So the only choice is to use Platform MBeanServer. I was very disappointed too when I came to know that the awesome JBoss JMX console is gone. But there is no other choice, I am using jconsole to view my MBean attributes and invoke any methods.

This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/standard.html) will give you a pretty good head start on writing standard platform mbeans.